# Why am I getting Hidden size error with PyTorch RNN

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to build a RNN for next word prediction, following a next character prediction example ([tutorial](https://blog.floydhub.com/a-beginners-guide-on-recurrent-neural-networks-with-pytorch/), [github](https://github.com/gabrielloye/RNN-walkthrough/blob/master/main.ipynb?ref=blog.floydhub.com), [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eh5z5A6i0FQamCNfFmsy831RthFHTVHy?usp=sharing) (runtime ~1min)).

In the example, the input shape is (3,14,17) for batch_size, sequence_length and nb_features. Then the hidden size is defined as (1,3,12) for n_layers, batch_size and hidden_dim.

I followed this example except for my batch_size is 1. Also, my input sequences are not padded since I'm using batch_size 1. So I run my train() method and I get an error on my first training data example :
`RuntimeError: Expected hidden size (1, 25, 12), got [1, 1, 12]` (25 being the sequence length).

So it seems pytorch ask me to give sequence length as dimension for my hidden layer but in the example code I followed it isn't the case and the code works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Additionally, here is the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1osTAsIXJDrV1xvAzi1S4X3EZu0mo47xT?usp=sharing) I am using (runtime ~1min).

Comment: You probably need `batch_first=True`. Post your relevant code _here_.

Comment: @erip Right, in the example code I use there is `batch_first=True`, gonna try with that thx

Comment: @erip the code computes further, but now I get an error at the loss computation step. I get `Expected input batch_size (25) to match target batch_size (23475)` when `input_shape (1,25,939)` and target_shape is same

Comment: Your target is not batched correctly. Again, post your code here (not a link).

Comment: @erip There is not much room to do so, the code is quite big.. I posted link to the colab at the end of the question. Here it is again : [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1osTAsIXJDrV1xvAzi1S4X3EZu0mo47xT?usp=sharing). I noticed though in the example code the target shape is different from input shape. For input (3,14,17) there is target (3,14) which I don't get since 17 is the output dimension (17 possible characters for the next character to predict).

Comment: @erip That's it, it computes ! I'm using one-hot for words and instead of giving sparse vector as target I had to give only the index thus saving one dimension to my target. Thanks so much for help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 main differences between the example code I use and my code which couldn't compute :
1- `batch_first=True` passed to the RNN when initiating the model
2- the target preprocessing had to differ from the input preprocessing : I am using sparse one-hot vectors to encode words and while sparse vectors work in input, the target had to be encoded with only the index of the word in the one-hot instead of the whole one-hot vector

Thanks @erip for help debugging this!